# Updating a local mercurial copy with a specific commit from another remote site

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, coin3d

*(I'm using real examples, so it is clearer.)*

I cloned an official Mercurial repository locally

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/Coin3D/soqt -r default
```

from this repo: https://bitbucket.org/Coin3D/soqt/branch/default

Now I want to update my local copy with a commit taken from a remote fork of the main project:

https://bitbucket.org/roboticslibrary/soqt/branch/patch-hidpi

How can I integrate a specific commit from a remote fork (#214c74a in this example) into my local clone?

With git I would add the remote fork, then I would use "fetch" on that and then I would use "cherry-pick" to get the specific commit.

Is that possible at all in Mercurial?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: of course. In exactly that way. You don't even need to add any remote site, just pull that commit into your repo and be done.

Comment: If you need a cherry pick, `hg graft` is the command.